# How to set jQuery this when calling a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery, I set a link tag's click handler like this:

```
$('#lnk').click(handleClick);
```

handleClick does something like this:

```
function handleClick() {
    var $this = $(this);
    ...
}
```

Now I have a need to directly call handleClick() outside of #lnk being clicked.  Is there a way for me to set `this` when calling handleClick?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply) or [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
handleClick.call(theElementThatShouldBeThis);
```

But of course `theElementThatShouldBeThis` must be a DOM element or something that is accepted as input for `jQuery()`.

And it becomes more tricky if you are accessing the `event` element inside `handleClick`. But I will just assume you don't ;)

You can also always execute the event handler in the context of `#lnk` by calling `$('#lnk').click()` (which simulates a click).

Comment: I don't see those in the jQuery API.  Are those plugins?  Have any links?

Comment: Those are built into javascript

Comment: @slolife: I linked to the corresponding documentation. These are methods of every function.

Comment: Yep, momentary lapse of sanity there.  I had hoped I'd be able to delete that comment before it was noticed, but, nope.

Comment: `call()` will call the function in that moment, the event is bound to the element and not when i click... any sugestions?

Comment: @Mephiztopheles: don't use call and just bind the handler?

Comment: but i need other parameters. I am programming with classes. called as `new FancyScroll()` e.g. and when i want to bind a click to an element and give as parameters the FancyScroll-Class, it doesn't work

Answer (score 5):

I think you're looking for "call" or "apply":

#### Call

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

#### Apply

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

#### From MDC

```
var result = fun.apply(thisArg, [argsArray]);

or

var result = fun.call(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Function.apply and pass in the DOM element returned by the query.

```
handleClick.apply($('#lnk')[0]);
```

Or better yet, let jQuery simulate a click on the element (Assuming you've already attached the click event handler).

```
$('#lnk').click();
```