# Cant return id value when using this and onclick()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

html:

```
<div class="ui blue button" id="f{{i}}" onclick="Dailer()">Get this!</div>
```

which returns:

```
<div class="ui blue button" id="f1" onclick="Dailer()">Get this</div>
```

And when I use JS:

```
function Dailer() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
}
```

I get `undefined` , even when using `alert(this.id)` doesent work.

But if I run the code on console, it works:

```
$("#f1").attr("id")
"f1"
```

Comment: `onclick="Dailer.call(this)"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set jQuery this when calling a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945281/how-to-set-jquery-this-when-calling-a-function)

Comment: Don't use inline onclick functions. Why not use `add.eventListener`?

Comment: @ArunPJohny that worked! thank you!
evolutionxbox is it deprecated? or doesent work when returning variables?
Terry thanks for the link

Comment: @ArunPJohny can you please write it as answer so i can validate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to pass `this` as an argument of the function

```
<div class="ui blue button" id="f1" onclick="Dailer(this)">Get this</div>
```

then the definition of your js function would be :

```
function Dailer(that) {
    alert($(that).attr('id'));
}
```

Comment: It would be better to use an EventListener but in the context the answer is the right one.

Comment: ah! thank you! so it was the problem about variable :(